# Solve $2+ \cos{\frac{3x}{2}} + \sqrt{3} \sin{\frac{3x}{2}} = 4\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$2+ \cos{\frac{3x}{2}} + \sqrt{3} \sin{\frac{3x}{2}} = 4\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}$$

My try:

$$ \cos{\frac{3x}{2}} + \sqrt{3} \sin{\frac{3x}{2}} = \sqrt{4}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \sin{\frac{3x}{2}} + \frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{3x}{2}}\right) = 2\sin\left({\frac{3x}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6}}\right)
$$

$$
2+  2\sin\left({\frac{3x}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6}}\right) = 4\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}
$$

$$
2\sin\left({\frac{3x}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6}}\right) + \cos{\frac{x}{2}}=0
$$

And then...

Comment: There was an error in the last line : 
$\;4\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}-2=-2\cos{\frac{x}{2}}\;$
so that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2+2\sin(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})=4 \sin^2(\frac{x}{4})$ simplifies to $2\sin(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})+2 cos(\frac{x}{2})=0$

$\sin(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})=-cos(\frac{x}{2})$

$\sin(\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{6})=sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\frac{x}{2})$

I hope you can solve further.

Comment: It's cool to accept reduction formula here! I forgot about it

Answer (score 2):

We have $$2+ \cos{\frac{3x}{2}} + \sqrt{3} \sin{\frac{3x}{2}} = 4\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}$$ $$1+\frac{1}{2}\cos{\frac{3x}{2}} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin{\frac{3x}{2}} = \frac{4}{2}\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}$$
$$\cos{\frac{3x}{2}}\cos \frac{\pi}{3} +\sin{\frac{3x}{2}}\sin\frac{\pi}{3} =-\left(1-2\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}}\right)$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-\cos \frac{x}{2}=\cos \left(\pi-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ Now, writing the general solution as follows $$\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi\pm \left(\pi-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ taking positive sign, we get $$\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi+ \left(\pi-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$  $$2x=2n\pi+ \frac{4\pi}{3}$$  $$\color{blue}{ x=n\pi+\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$ taking negative sign, we get
$$\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi- \left(\pi-\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
$$x=2n\pi-\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\color{blue}{ x=2n\pi-\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$ Where, $n$ is any integer.

Comment: I'm sorry. Your second anwer is not correct. According to my book and my calculas its: $2\frac{\pi}{3} + \pi n , 4 \frac{\pi}{3} +  2 \pi n $

Comment: Could you please give some reasons or explain why?

Comment: I'm trying to find them

Comment: I found it: $ 1-2\sin^2{\frac{x}{4}} = \cos{\frac{x}{2}} , not \cos{2x}$

Comment: Kindly, check out your second solution $x=4\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi$ is wrong. It must be $x=2n\pi-2\frac{\pi}{3}$. You may check it out in the answer I edited.

Comment: I recalculated, You are right.